# Storing Files during development from IOS App

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, storing-data

I like to write a static database which is fetched from an url to the local disk of my IOS app, during development and using the IOS Simulator.

The guidelines of Apple suggest to use the Caches directory for that:

```
Data that can be downloaded again or regenerated should be stored in the <Application_Home>/Library/Caches directory.
```

for that I used the following code (in my sample its a simple textfile)

```
let dirs : [String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]
        if ((dirs) != nil) {
            let dir = dirs![0]; //documents directory
            let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("testfile.txt");
            let text = "some text"

            println("Pfad : " + path);

            //writing
            text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);

            //reading
            let text2 = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        }
```

as you can see I used NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory as the guideline suggested.

Then the File is stored under:

```
/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/19E2CB7E-3ABB-4C0A-8B49-39A0BE392A93/data/Containers/Data/Application/F7455C1D-FEF2-49A1-8F21-4A3B19D59CAB/Library/Caches/testfile.txt
```

Now I realized, that at every start of a new IOS Simulator the Path is different, because every instance of IOS Simulator has its own DeviceID in the Path.

I would like to follow the guidelines, but do not want to have different pathes.
My Usecase: My app downloads a big file from an URL. If the File is downloaded once, I like to use the File after every next start without downloading the entire file again. But in my actual development environment my app always would download the file again.

any help ?

Comment: Load stored file with path you used to save and it will works.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correct. You want me to set the path static to the path i saved first ?

Comment: No! Read from this path: let dir = dirs![0]; //documents directory
            let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("testfile.txt");

Comment: I do not understand. I did this at start, but then I recognized that the path to the textfile.txt does not exist, because in the meanwhile dirs![0] is different. Every new start of the IOS Simulator gives a new dirs![0] back.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your cache path to file:

```
func cachePathForFile(fileName: String)->NSURL? {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var error:NSError?
    var documentsDir = fileManager.URLForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory, inDomain: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true, error: &error)
    var fileUrl = documentsDir?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    return fileUrl
}
```

Write and read:

```
// get path
    var fileUrl = self.cachePathForFile("test.txt")
    var text = "text"
    var error: NSError?

    // write
    if fileUrl != nil {
        text.writeToURL(fileUrl!, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
    }

    // read
    if fileUrl != nil {
        var fileText = String(contentsOfURL: fileUrl!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
        println("\(fileText)")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks iOSfleer. I know this. But this is only valid for one session. First start of the IOS-Simulator will work perfect writing and reading. But the second start creates a new store location and I can't read the previously stored data. And of course this is how it should be for caching. So I guess I misunderstood the guidelines. So where should I store data on disk for my application, which should be persistent ?

Comment: On second start, path is different but App can find it and read the stored text.